# Does Linux require Python?

Tags: linux, python, android, distributions

One of my friends told me that without Python, Linux cannot get ip, cannot open network stack and can't make "port switching", even he thinks kernel can't boot without Python. Is python really a requirement for a Linux system or it is just another tool like other interpreters, languages etc...

He says Android has already Python inside.

Comment: It appears your friend is mistaken in more ways than one.

Comment: well I was trying to convince him, but I give up in the end... He doesn't accepts and I don't care any more...

Comment: Your friend is correct to state that [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html) is not Linux.

Comment: busybox *is* linux and android does *not* have python inside.

Comment: yes @DigitalTrauma, it is linux in their website "BusyBox - The Swiss Army Knife of Embedded Linux"

Comment: @mosvy Since when Busybox _is_ Linux? That's a most extraordinary statement.

OP: No, it is not the case that "the Swiss Army Knife of Linux" *is* Linux anymore than "the best antivirus for Windows" _is_ Windows. "Linux" is a kernel. Busybox is a toolset and/or Live CD that works with/uses the Linux kernel, just like Android, Debian or (probably) your smart TV.

Comment: @TobiaTesan yes and Redmond is not Microsoft, and the Pentagon is just a building. Thanks for educating me.

Comment: @tanaydin.  That motto is in no way proof of what you state.  If you want to quote the BusyBox site, then "BusyBox combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a single small executable".  In other words, BusyBox is an entirely optional utility set found in some Linux distros (especially embedded distros).  It is also sometimes part of BSD-based distros.  This does not imply that BusyBox is BSD.  For fun, I deleted `/bin/busybox` from my Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu is a common linux distro).  Apparently Ubuntu functions just fine without BusyBox.

Comment: @mosvy then why are you suggesting, and I quote, that "busybox *is* linux"? Just to troll poor OP, who's already confused enough?

Comment: This question should not be closed. It shows serious misinformation, but it's **not** opinion based, nor is it off topic. Those an op should delete these comments.

Comment: Voting to leave closed on account of [OP giving up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474623/does-linux-require-python#comment867007_474623) and as "too broad", given the confusion regarding Linux-the-kernel vs Linux-the-distribution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Python is not mandatory for Linux, and there are plenty of small "embedded" Linux systems that don't have it.

However, many *distributions* require it.  So RHEL may have a dependency on Python because some of their management tools and scripts have been written in it.  On those systems python is a requirement.

Comment: And RHEL uses 2.7.x of python, not the latest version.

Comment: This answer would be much improved by addressing whether Android specifically requires it, since the question is tagged [tag:android] and not [tag:linux]. @mdpc And trying to upgrade it in place will break the entire system.

Answer (score 20):

Python isn’t necessary, and it’s easy to prove: a basic Debian installation can get on the network etc. but doesn’t have Python.

Python is an interpreter like any other. It can be required in some distributions, if their core tools (package managers etc.) are written in Python; other interpreters are required without anyone making a fuss about it (Perl for example, or a POSIX-style shell). Because Python is so widely used nowadays, many distributions install it by default in their standard setup, even if they don’t absolutely require it.

As far as Android is concerned, you need Python to build it and to run some of the development tools (starting with [Repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop)). The Android operating system, as run on target devices, doesn’t include Python.

Comment: Unless you're talking about a custom install of Debian, it _does_ have Python by default, it's just not used for any of the standard networking code.

Comment: @Austin the standard installation does, but the basic installation doesn’t.

Comment: What does require Perl? I would make a fuss about it :-)

Comment: @Bergi in Debian, various important tools such as `adduser`, `debconf`, some support scripts used by `locales`... You also need Perl to build most Debian packages since many of `dpkg-dev`’s tools are written in Perl. (`dpkg` itself doesn’t involve Perl, nor does `rpm`, except when building Perl-using RPMs.)

Answer (score 5):

It isn't necesarry in terms that the system won't function if it isn't there but some distros have tools that are written in Python.

Anaconda, which is the installer for RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, Oracle Linux, and Scientific Linux, is written in Python as are `yum` and `dnf` which are the package managers. They also require Python to function so if something is wrong with it, they won't work.

`portage`, which is the package manager for Gentoo, is also written in Python.

Comment: A lot of the modern system management functionality In RHEL requires Python. One example is `firewall-cmd`